# Can i decrypt then decompress a file in 'request-promise' GET callback function?

Tags: node.js, encryption, filesystems

I want to decrypt and decompress a file while downloading it from cloud. Can i? Is it possible to decrypt and decompress a file in stream?

Here is my file downloading script without decrypting and decompressing.

By the way i didnt choose any decrypting and decompressing algorithm yet. I hope i can use any algorithm what i want. I want to do this in stream because i dont want to lose too much time while downloading, decrypting, decompressing. This is my graduation project.

```
var rp = require('request-promise');

var downloadOptions = {
        uri: 'https://' + path.hosts[0] + path.path,
        method: 'GET',
        encoding: null,
    }

    rp(downloadOptions)
        .then(function (body) {

            let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('_obj.png');
            console.log(body)
            writeStream.write(body, 'binary');
            writeStream.on('finish', () => {
                console.log('wrote all data to file');
            });
            writeStream.end();

        })
        .catch(function (err) {

            console.log(err);

        })
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible, as long as you use libraries for crypt and compression that have a streaming or update/final - style API.

Comment: Thank you, i fouınd this https://gist.github.com/chris-rock/335f92742b497256982a after your comment. I will try something like this.